# How can I show daily schedules of all users in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-queryset

I'm using Django to make a website for gym trainers.
what I want is a template for the daily schedules of all trainers like this[image]

But, my page is 
[image]

The problem is the 'td' of per trainer's tr repeats as many as the number of schedules the trainer has. I know the `{% for sc in schedules %}` is the problem. But, because schedules are the query set, I should use the for and while using for, I should check the right time to insert the schedule to the right tr, td position.  How can I make the successful table to show the daily schedules of all users(trainers)?? Anybody will be very helpful to me.

Schedule.model

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
     Trainer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True,null=True, related_name='schedule', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=12,blank=True,)

     start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

my views.py

```
def staff_daily_schedule_search(request):

all_schedules = Schedule.objects.all()
Fitness_list = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Fitness') # Fitness Trainers

search_date1 = request.GET.get('search_date','') 
search_date= datetime.datetime.strptime(search_date1, '%Y-%m-%d') #%T = %H:%M:%S  '%Y-%m-%d'

schedules= Schedule.objects.none()
for f in Fitness_list:
    sc = f.schedule.filter(start__year=search_date.year).filter(start__month = search_date.month).filter(start__day = search_date.day)
    print(sc)
    schedules |= sc

context = {
    'search_date' : search_date1 if search_date1 else datetime.date.today(),
    'Fitness_list':Fitness_list,
    'schedules' : schedules,
}
return render(request, 'management/staff_daily_schedule.html', context)
```

staff_daily_schedule.html

```
<form action="{% url 'management:staff_daily_schedule_search' %}" method="GET">
    <span><input type="date" class="search_date my-control" name="search_date" value="{{ search_date }}" ></span>
            <a id="today" class="btn btn-warning">오늘</a>
    <button class="btn btn-info" value="검색" >검색</button>
</form>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>06:00 </th>
        <th>07:00 ~ 07:50</th>
        <th>08:00 ~ 08:50</th>
        <th>09:00 ~ 09:50</th>
        <th>10:00 ~ 10:50</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for trainer in Fitness_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ trainer }} </td>

            {% for sc in schedules %} <!-- because of this for, td repeats as many as the number of schedule per trainer has..-->
            {% if sc.Trainer == trainer %}

                {% if sc.start.hour == 21 %} <!--HOUR of 6:00 a.m = 21-->
                    <td>{{ sc }}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td ></td>
                {% endif %}

                {% if sc.start.hour == 22 %}
                    <td>{{ sc }}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td ></td>
                {% endif %}

                {% if sc.start.hour == 23 %}
                    <td>{{ sc }}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td ></td>
                {% endif %}

                {% if sc.start.hour == 0 %} <!-- 9 a.m. -->
                    <td>{{ sc }}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td></td>
                {% endif %}

                {% if sc.start.hour == 1 %}
                    <td>{{ sc }}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td></td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}


    </tr>
    {% endfor %} <!-- tr repetition as trainers number-->

</tbody>

</table>
```

The problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the logic in your view instead of the template, it's easy to set up the table exactly like you want it.

[Edited to use an OrderedDict to preserve the order of trainers.]

views.py

```
def staff_daily_schedule_search(request):

    Fitness_list = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Fitness') # Fitness Trainers

    search_date1 = request.GET.get('search_date','') 
    search_date= datetime.datetime.strptime(search_date1, '%Y-%m-%d') #%T = %H:%M:%S  '%Y-%m-%d'

    trainer_dict = OrderedDict()
    # Initialize each row of the table with the trainer's name and a blank schedule
    for f in Fitness_list:
        trainer_dict[str(f.id)] = {'name': f.get_full_name(),  'hour_21': '', 
            'hour_22': '', 'hour_23': '', 'hour_0': '', 'hour_1': ''}

    schedules = Schedule.objects.filter(start__year=search_date.year).filter(start__month = 
        search_date.month).filter(start__day = search_date.day)
    # Insert each schedule item into the appropriate table row and cell
    for sc in schedules:
        trainer_dict[str(sc.Trainer.id)]['hour_' + str(sc.start.hour)] = sc.title

    context = {
        'search_date' : search_date1 if search_date1 else datetime.date.today(), 
        'trainer_dict': trainer_dict
    }
    return render(request, 'management/staff_daily_schedule.html', context)
```

staff_daily_schedule.html

```
<form action="{% url 'management:staff_daily_schedule_search' %}" method="GET">
    <span><input type="date" class="search_date my-control" name="search_date" value="{{ search_date }}" ></span>
            <a id="today" class="btn btn-warning">오늘</a>
    <button class="btn btn-info" value="검색" >검색</button>
</form>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>06:00 </th>
        <th>07:00 ~ 07:50</th>
        <th>08:00 ~ 08:50</th>
        <th>09:00 ~ 09:50</th>
        <th>10:00 ~ 10:50</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for trainer in trainer_dict %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ trainer.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ trainer.hour_21 }}</td>
            <td>{{ trainer.hour_22 }}</td>
            <td>{{ trainer.hour_23 }}</td>
            <td>{{ trainer.hour_0 }}</td>
            <td>{{ trainer.hour_1 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! But, trainer.hour_21   have an error : 'str' objects has no attribute 'hour_21'. So, {{ trainer.hour_21, 22..}} show nothing.

Comment: adding `trainer_dict = trainer_dict.items()`in views   and changing `{% for trainer, training in trainer_dict %}` `{{ training.hour_21}}` in template solved the problem. Thank you very much, evergreen!